# memory leak arc when assigning local var to property

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode-instruments

i am using ARC, my code is as :

```
 -(void)viewAllCustomer:(id)sender
{           
    if([self.popOver isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [self.popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }


    CustomersViewController *allCustomer=[[CustomersViewController alloc]init];
    [allCustomer setDelegateAction:self];

    [allCustomer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 370, 420)];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:allCustomer];
    UIPopoverController *_popOver=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navController];
    [_popOver setPassthroughViews:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self]];
    [_popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(370, 420)];
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;

    //    60.0, 54.0

    CGRect buttonFrame=CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x+25, button.frame.origin.y+35, 10,10);
    [_popOver presentPopoverFromRect:buttonFrame inView:self permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];


    self.popOver=_popOver;//popOver is (nonatomic,retain)
}
```

i am getting memory leak as:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: y r u trying to do self.popover = _popover

Comment: Why are you assigning popover to itself?

Comment: Why do you thing there is a leak? Have you run Xcode's Analyzer?

Comment: @Abizern, he doesn't. _popover is a local variable.

Comment: @Zaph the screen shot i have attached is from instruments->leak, that is showing leak.static analyser  not showing memory leak.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar the very first time i my self think why, actually in previous development code it is implemented so on around 100s of places, commenting it might make current code unstable.

Comment: @FreeNickname I'm surprised that it isn't throwing other warnings about shadowing the iVar. Using an underscore for a local variable is unconventional.

Comment: @Abizern But unconventional and terrible code is the norm these days. It seems that college courses are mainly about writing code to get the correct answer, not about how to write clean, concise and understandable code. Best practices of how to write code seem to be nonexistent. Last month I had several "coders" tell me that they saw no problem with a single method 8,000lines in length. Much coding these days seems to be happenstance rather than engineered. Little concern for conventions.

Comment: @Zaph That's why it's important to point it out. Many programmers new to iOS are unaware that there are conventions. I've even written mine up: http://abizern.org/cocoa-coding-conventions/ :)

Comment: @Abizern I like that, I will show this at this months CocoaHeads meeting.

Comment: @Abizern, I'm agree with you, I just wanted to mention, that the author doesn't actually assign _popOver to itself :) And thanks for your coding conventions link.

Comment: @Abizern i have removed the instance variable popOver and synthesise(the old ugly code), just made property (nonatomic, strong) popOver, and accessing in .m with self.popOver also i have removed that (self.popOver=_popOver;) assignment.No more memory leak.Thank you very much.Please post as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @Maddy You could just answer it yourself and accept it. That is perfectly acceptable behaviour on SO. My work here is done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i my self have to give answer of this question, thanks to @abizern.Actually the leak was due to _var._var is just a different name for the instance variable (presumably so you don't accidentally access directly it when you meant to use an accessor).In the code provided to me  was accidentally assigning _var to self.var.
i simply made the @property(nonatomic, retain) and use it as self.var in implementation file.No more memory leaks .Also in arc property are auto synthesise, so no more need to explicitly @synthesise removed.

while going through developer apple i found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html):
In this example, it’s clear that myString is a local variable and _someString is an instance variable.

In general, you should use accessor methods or dot syntax for property access even if you’re accessing an object’s properties from within its own implementation, in which case you should use self:

```
- (void)someMethod {
NSString *myString = @"An interesting string";//my bad was that i have taken _myString

self.someString = myString;//again self.someString = _myString //wrong
```

// or[self setSomeString:myString];
}